# In bot framework composer in Teams channel is there a way to determine file size of an uploaded file?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams, bot-framework-composer

Bot framework composer in web channel gives you file sizes as an array in turn.activity.channelData.attachmentSizes (these don't always line up with the array order of the attachments but it's better than nothing).

However in Teams channel there's no attachment detail other than the url, some download url involving an id, and what the file says its extension is.

In response to [this suggestion](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/199058/sharepoint-fast-way-to-detect-file-size-by-uri-using-rest) I  tried https://<sharepointsite>/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/path/to/filename.ext')**/Properties** but it returned 403 Forbidden.

I'm wondering if Graph API is the only way (I'd rather not have to get users to agree to that) or if there's some rest api that can gather it for me?

Comment: There are two ways to send files to and receive files from a bot:1. Graph Api 2. Bot API
But the Bot API is only supporting files in personal context.
Graph APIs work in all Teams scopes.
Reference Doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/bots-filesv4

Comment: Also, there is rest API as you mention above, please follow this document to use the rest api - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn450841(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#endpoint-uri

Comment: Ok thanks Sayali. I only need personal context. From what you say it seems there is no way to get file size from Bot API. I have proceeded to download the file and get the content length to determine it's size.